# Linear else if statements, how do i convert this into a refactored code

Tags: python

The "anykey" has not been used btw

def load1():
print(
"Please choose your region\n 1 for Region 1\n 2 for CAR \n 3 for Region II\n 4 for Region III\n 5 for Region IV\n 6 for NCR\n 7 for Region V\n 8 for Region VI\n 9 for Region VII\n 10 for SOCCSKARGEN\n 11 for Region VIII\n 12 for CARAGA\n 13 for Region IX\n 14 for Region X\n 15 for Region XI ")
option = int(input("Your option: "))
# Acts like switch
if option == "1":
print("Region 1\n")
csv_file = csv.reader(open('file/Region I.csv', 'r'))
for row in csv_file:
print(row)
anykey = input("Press any key to return from main menu")
mainMenu()

```
elif option == "2":
    print("CAR\n")
    csv_file = csv.reader(open('file/CAR.csv', 'r'))
    for row in csv_file:
        print(row)
    anykey = input("Press any key to return from main menu")
    mainMenu()

elif option == "3":
    print("Region 2\n")
    csv_file = csv.reader(open('file/Region II.csv', 'r'))
    for row in csv_file:
        print(row)
    anykey = input("Press any key to return from main menu")
    mainMenu()

elif option == 4:

    print("Region 3\n")
    csv_file = csv.reader(open('file/Region III.csv', 'r'))
    for row in csv_file:
        print(row)
    anykey = input("Press any key to return from main menu")
    mainMenu()

elif option == 5:
    print("Region 4\n")
    csv_file = csv.reader(open('file/Region IV.csv', 'r'))
    for row in csv_file:
        print(row)
    anykey = input("Press any key to return from main menu")
    mainMenu()

elif option == 6:
    print("NCR 4\n")
    csv_file = csv.reader(open('file/NCR.csv', 'r'))
    for row in csv_file:
        print(row)
        print()
    anykey = input("Press any key to return from main menu")
    mainMenu()

elif option == 7:
    print("Region 5\n")
    csv_file = csv.reader(open('file/Region V.csv', 'r'))
    for row in csv_file:
        print(row)
    anykey = input("Press any key to return from main menu")
    mainMenu()

elif option == 8:
    print("Region 6\n")
    csv_file = csv.reader(open('file/Region VI.csv', 'r'))
    for row in csv_file:
        print(row)
    anykey = input("Press any key to return from main menu")
    mainMenu()

elif option == 9:
    print("Region 7\n")
    csv_file = csv.reader(open('file/Region VII.csv', 'r'))
    for row in csv_file:
        print(row)
    anykey = input("Press any key to return from main menu")
    mainMenu()

elif option == 10:
    print("SOCCSKARGEN\n")
    csv_file = csv.reader(open('file/SOCCSKARGEN.csv', 'r'))
    for row in csv_file:
        print(row)
    anykey = input("Press any key to return from main menu")
    mainMenu()

elif option == 11:
    print("Region 8\n")
    csv_file = csv.reader(open('file/Region VIII.csv', 'r'))
    for row in csv_file:
        print(row)
    anykey = input("Press any key to return from main menu")
    mainMenu()

elif option == 12:
    print("CARAGA\n")
    csv_file = csv.reader(open('file/CARAGA.csv', 'r'))
    for row in csv_file:
        print(row)
    anykey = input("Press any key to return from main menu")
    mainMenu()

elif option == 13:
    print("Region 9\n")
    csv_file = csv.reader(open('file/Region IX.csv', 'r'))
    for row in csv_file:
        print(row)
    anykey = input("Press any key to return from main menu")
    mainMenu()

elif option == 14:
    print("Region 10\n")
    csv_file = csv.reader(open('file/Region X.csv', 'r'))
    for row in csv_file:
        print(row)
    anykey = input("Press any key to return from main menu")
    mainMenu()

elif option == 15:
    print("Region 11\n")
    csv_file = csv.reader(open('file/Region XI.csv', 'r'))
    for row in csv_file:
        print(row)
    anykey = input("Press any key to return from main menu")
    mainMenu()
```

Comment: What is your question? What are you trying to do? Why do you think you need a dictionary?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic) and [ask]. Please [edit] your question to explicitly include a _specific_ question about your code.

Comment: What do you mean by "put a dictionary in it" ? Do you want the function to use a dictionary ? Do you want to map the answer of the fonction on a dictionary ? Anything else ?

Comment: I would like to refractor it. But I'm just new in refractoring

Comment: We still don't know what you mean. Be _specific_, add details about the problem you want to solve and what you have tried to solve it and how those attempts fell short.

Comment: this will help you https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/182093/why-store-a-function-inside-a-python-dictionary/182095

Answer (score 2):

If you want your selections to be in a dictionary, store function names in it and then call them:

```
# load(), search() and mainMenu() are defined above somewhere

def print_and_exit():
    print("Thank you for using the program.")
    exit()

def invalid_choice():
    print("Invalid choice, please select from 1 to 3")
    mainMenu()

selections={"1":load1, "2":search, "3":print_and_exit}

def select(selection):
    # call the function associated with the selection, or indicate that an invalid choice was made
    selections.get(selection, invalid_choice)()  # invalid_choice() is called if the choice is not in the selections dictionary
```

Comment: To clean this up a little more, you can make an `invalid` function to use as the default in `selections.get()`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice done, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: As an observation, this refactor removes the need for the `select()` function at all. Don't get me wrong, this is probably the best answer with the information given since the OP didn't post the `menu()` function or wherever `select()` is called.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice agreed, since it's a one-liner then it could be simplified by just using that line instead of the function, unless it's used in a lot of places, in which case a function makes more sense in case anything needs to be refactored down the road.

Comment: Good point that having the function increases reusability. Also, after I posted that comment, I realized that the function adds a level of abstraction that helps understanding for us lowly humans. The one-liner is a bit obtuse and takes some time to decipher where as a single `select(s)` call is much easier to parse.